# Peergroup download of the blockchain stalls?

Tags: blockchain, client

I'm using bitcoinsharp to build my client. I try to download the blockchain in a peergroup network. Download starts, but when progress is 98%, the download is stopped & the client is waiting (2 hours without any change). The size of the downloaded blockchain file is 4.5 MB.

I use the following code:

```
PeerGroup peerGroup = new PeerGroup(blockStore, @params, chain);
peerGroup.AddAddress(new PeerAddress(IPAddress.Parse("84.38.65.102")));
peerGroup.AddAddress(new PeerAddress(IPAddress.Parse("83.23.15.71")));
peerGroup.Start();
peerGroup.DownloadBlockChain();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the latest libraries?

Comment: yes ,  I checkout http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinsharp/source/ ..

Comment: And i try BoundedOverheadBlockStore, DiskBlockStore , MemoryBlockStore  create blockchain but same result.

Comment: Hi Stephane,
Try your edited version and  dont finished download.

Comment: Maybe it's just because there are so many transactions it's taking a while?

Comment: can you segment the download?  The block chain is really several chunks, divided by transaction groups and it could very well be an issue that the size changed over time.  Basically treat the block chain as a download of unknown file size?

Answer (score 1):

The library is abandoned 7 years ago, and I don't see that anybody picked it up for maintenance https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bitcoinsharp&type= Try to base your application on a library that is still maintained.

Comment: The question was also asked 7 years ago.